# If one says "Amid much fanfare", what does he mean?

Tags: idioms

Just complete an [article](http://dailychilli.com/sports/5-sports/15037-yao-ming-becomes-management-school-freshman) about Yao Ming, who is a great basketball star in NBA. The only thing I fail to understand is the phrase "Amid much fanfare" in this sentence:

> Amid much fanfare, Yao Ming, 31, announced his retirement on July 20
>   from the  National Basketball Association's Houston Rockets, the US
>   team who made him a global star, and the Chinese national team five
>   days later.

After turning to Google and a dictionary for help, it seems still not so clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this second [meaning](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/fanfare):

> **fanfare** NOUN
>    ˈfænfeə(r)  ˈfænfer
>
> **1** [countable]
>   a short loud piece of music that is played to celebrate somebody/something important arriving
>   - *A fanfare of trumpets will sound for the Queen.*
>
> **2** [uncountable, countable]
>   a large amount of activity and discussion on television, in newspapers, etc. to celebrate somebody/something
>   - *The product was launched amid much fanfare worldwide.
>
>   - Despite the fanfare of publicity that accompanied its launch, his latest novel sold only a few hundred copies.*

Answer (score 2):

The phrase

> *Amid much fanfare*

is composed of

**Amid**

> (prep.) In the midst or **middle of**; surrounded or encompassed by; among.

**fanfare**

> a large amount of activity and discussion on television, in newspapers, etc. to **celebrate** somebody/something

So the combined meaning is:

> In the middle of a lot of celebration

(celebration might not be the right word here, depending on the context - fanfare could stand also for a situation where there is no literal celebration, but there is a lot of talk, speculation and/or praise directed at someone; a lot of audible activity directed at someone)

Comment: I'm not sure what dictionary you consulted, but "fanfare" I believe was originally the little trumpet tune played by heralds to announce the entrance of the King (or Duke or whatever).

Comment: Popular depictions of ancient Rome also includes fanfares (though the evidence is not conclusive)

Comment: In this sense it just means "a lot of noise"

Answer (score 1):

In the words of the [OED](http://www.oed.com), a *fanfare* is:

> A flourish, call, or short tune, sounded by trumpets, bugles, or
>   hunting-horns.

By extension, it can be used figuratively and, as in your example, rather loosely, to describe the extravagant and colourful way in which any outstanding event is marked.